How to configure Azure Pipelines agent pool based on a Windows Virtual Machine Scale Set and using Azure File Share for agent workspace?
Given:

Must use Windows agent pool
Must do all the configuration silently in a scripted way.
Want to use VMSS based agent pool
Does not want to join the VM instances to the corporate AD domain
Azure File Share to be used as the agent workspace - for the sake of experiment

Done so far:

Provisioned Azure Windows VMSS and Azure Storage Account for File Share
Configured Custom Script Extension to mount the Azure File Share and instruct the Azure Pipeline extension to use the Azure File Share as the agent workspace.

Problems:

The agent is unable to execute any Powershell code from the Azure File Share due to execution policy restrictions.

The error is something like this:
Starting: CmdLine
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.237.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Import-Module : AuthorizationManager check failed.
At line:1 char:631
+ ... Verbose } ; Import-Module -Name 'Z:\a\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
Invoke-VstsTaskScript : The term 'Invoke-VstsTaskScript' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
At line:1 char:902
+ ... $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -Script ...
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-VstsTaskScript:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe', arguments '-NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if ([Console]::InputEncoding -is [Text.UTF8Encoding] -and [Console]::InputEncoding.GetPreamble().Length -ne 0) { [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false } if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; Import-Module -Name 'Z:\a\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9\2.237.1\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''Z:\a\_tasks\CmdLine_d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9\2.237.1\cmdline.ps1'''))"'.
Finishing: CmdLine


There are a lot of sources on the Internet instructing what to do, but nothing worked for me. Also, all of them ask to run gpedit.msc interactively, which is not good for me, because I need a non interactive solution. Besides, I tried this and it did not work.
Here is the script run by the Custom Script extension for Windows VMSS:
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$AccountName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$AccessKey,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$DriveLetter
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'STOP'
if (Get-PSDrive -Name $DriveLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    return
}

if ($env:PATH -notmatch ';C:\\AzureCLI\\bin(?:;|$)') {
    $env:PATH += ";C:\AzureCLI\bin"
}

if (!(Get-Command az -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    # Get Azure CLI
    $AzureCLIZipFileName = "installazurecliwindowszipx64"
    $Archive = "C:\AzureCLI\$AzureCLIZipFileName"

    if (!(Test-Path $Archive)) {
        $Subject = "https://aka.ms/$AzureCLIZipFileName to $Archive"
        "Downloading $Subject ..."

        mkdir C:\AzureCLI -Force > $null
        Set-Location C:\AzureCLI
        curl.exe -fsLO https://aka.ms/$AzureCLIZipFileName
        
        if ($LASTEXITCODE) {
            throw "Failed to download $Subject"
        }
    }
    $StaleItems = Get-ChildItem -Exclude $AzureCLIZipFileName
    if ($StaleItems) {
        Remove-Item -r -force $StaleItems
    }
    
    "Unzipping $Archive ..."

    Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'
    [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($Archive, 'C:\AzureCLI')
    Remove-Item $AzureCLIZipFileName
}

# Create Azure File Share
$AzureFileShareName = $env:COMPUTERNAME.ToLower()
$Subject = "Azure File Share $AccountName\$AzureFileShareName"
"Creating $Subject ..."

az storage share create -n $AzureFileShareName --account-name $AccountName --account-key $AccessKey
if ($LASTEXITCODE) {
    throw "Failed to create $Subject"
}

# Mount Azure File Share
$Subject += " to ${DriveLetter}:"
"Mounting $Subject ..."

$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "$AccountName.file.core.windows.net" -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
    $UserName = "localhost\$AccountName"
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $AccessKey -AsPlainText -Force
    $creds = [Management.Automation.PSCredential]::New($UserName, $Password)
    New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath "\\$AccountName.file.core.windows.net\$AzureFileShareName" -Credential $creds -LocalPath "${DriveLetter}:" -Persistent $true
}
else {
    throw "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route to tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
}

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("VSTS_AGENT_INPUT_WORK", "${DriveLetter}:\a", "Machine")

This script installs Azure CLI, creates and mounts the Azure File Share and instructs the Azure Pipelines extension to use the Azure File Share as the agent work directory.
The VMSS uses the 2022-datacenter-azure-edition Windows Server image.
I have plans to try the same experiment with Azure Disk and maybe Azure NetApp Files. But for now I want to make it work with Azure File Share.
Is there a way to resolve it without GUI and without joining the VM to the corporate domain?

Does this issue only occur when running PowerShell files from Azure file share? If you run the Powershell file from VMSS machine directly, will it work?

No, it does not. It requires me to set execution policy. So it is consistent. Or to call Unblock-File

I can reproduce the same situation when enabling the PowerShell execution policy. I am afraid that there is no non interactive solution can meet your requirement. We need to log in to the VM instance and manually unblock file or disable the powershell execution policy. Since this policy prevents tasks in the pipeline from running, we cannot integrate the steps into the pipeline. We need to disable the policy first and then execute the pipeline

That kind of sucks.
